# How to compute Spearman's Rho Trend test in r

Tags: r, statistics, trend

I am trying to compute Spearman's Rho Trend test in r by doing this:

```
test=cor.test(timeseries,1:n,method="spearman")
D=test$p.value
Z=D*sqrt((n-2)/(1-D^2))
pt(Z,n-2)
```

First, I calculate the Correlation coefficient and then I compute the test itself but it show a p-val=1, but I am not sure about it.
Have some Idea about it?

DATA:

```
c(1.87475, 2.84528, 5.83542, 10.8843, 9.48484, 10.0332, 7.16305, 
9.15246, 8.68957, 11.2653, 8.76863, 4.0485, 2.8528, 3.06203, 
3.5859, 7.12124, 9.51561, 9.22085, 7.81098, 6.73397, 8.58113, 
9.28353, 7.92128, 5.04925, 2.2428, 5.99153, 4.70723, 11.9191, 
12.9951, 10.2102, 7.5542, 8.72667, 8.2311, 10.2064, 7.785, 5.25303, 
3.96196, 5.74908, 5.26922, 12.4321, 11.7044, 7.14123, 7.08435, 
6.12911, 8.59358, 10.3117, 5.85105, 3.75807, 2.01575, 2.96886, 
5.07536, 11.4144, 9.51971, 7.5381, 8.22469, 7.20163, 8.34905, 
8.94548, 6.15442, 6.34244, 4.3739, 6.79443, 4.20708, 7.69045, 
9.65889, 10.433, 8.44214, 8.89671, 10.4557, 10.1401, 8.95852, 
3.38102, 2.17563, 2.27429, 4.9568, 7.20546, 9.2164, 7.46578, 
7.55419, 8.58356, 8.98944, 9.16541, 6.9009, 3.97315, 3.09716, 
4.49597, 4.27927, 10.046, 9.51468, 9.45756, 6.27443, 7.19989, 
7.55478, 11.4173, 6.34512, 3.20048, 2.3346, 3.33158, 4.66627, 
8.50802, 9.19616, 6.36604, 9.81922, 7.56599, 9.23924, 11.0332, 
7.07433, 3.9774, 1.9611, 3.76258, 2.31831, 8.63655, 8.92169, 
9.55649, 8.78941, 10.7815, 9.44618, 10.553, 10.0151, 5.71694, 
3.93641, 4.37566, 5.11101, 5.75034, 9.61361, 9.02001, 6.91823, 
8.05951, 9.45761, 9.05592, 6.20638, 3.86533, 3.66949, 3.73916, 
5.74735, 10.0382, 9.1558, 7.4962, 7.15291, 6.52209, 6.69322, 
10.9919, 7.80923, 4.86516, 1.92499, 2.95135, 5.23056, 7.86658, 
9.41144, 8.60926, 7.72269, 6.09726, 8.25809, 7.08823, 8.36145, 
2.95296, 2.54423, 2.73502, 3.29865, 7.45659, 9.55943, 7.027, 
7.93852, 7.54321, 8.27874, 6.41406, 7.52643, 4.27732, 4.21357, 
2.9732, 6.63207, 9.51842, 10.0635, 7.22504, 7.09003, 6.64774, 
9.19645, 8.34171, 8.48366, 4.19497, 3.01118, 4.07612, 6.98124, 
9.93061, 10.1801, 8.25671, 7.2361, 8.35503, 8.14476, 8.91099, 
9.02474, 3.48103, 1.85194, 1.59392, 5.19668, 9.30066, 9.28724, 
10.0509, 9.0745, 8.85791, 8.15646, 9.7758, 6.412, 5.88048, 3.58275, 
5.99374, 6.65659, 8.27649, 11.0066, 9.92089, 8.5654, 8.75503, 
8.3944, 9.63843, 7.50948, 5.10784, 3.81126, 5.71426, 3.25419, 
7.82241, 8.74966, 8.39693, 5.91505, 4.89234, 8.0544, 6.70593, 
7.04475, 1.57748, 1.64281, 4.33555, 5.11418, 9.60619, 11.1262, 
8.80311, 9.4623, 8.70307, 8.50093, 9.58583, 7.89205, 6.20712, 
4.8317, 8.51534, 5.2159, 10.6988, 8.93205, 9.88138, 6.85288, 
7.71208, 10.5172, 10.4221, 8.69456, 6.54457, 3.46086, 5.82024, 
5.669, 8.66004, 11.7918, 9.41083, 8.77455, 8.43954, 10.7036, 
9.47817, 7.23946, 5.07723, 2.59331, 2.09574, 6.07388, 6.69522, 
10.5635, 8.25802, 8.29898, 6.15296, 9.65629, 9.25886, 8.72526, 
6.65301, 2.71164, 2.57094, 6.10028, 9.82986, 9.97061, 8.72147, 
7.78037, 7.16719, 8.05045, 8.41613, 6.90927, 5.00483, 1.58178, 
3.20776, 5.53643, 9.84159, 9.91302, 9.99696, 7.65637, 7.49268, 
8.97894, 10.0529, 8.63098, 5.56845, 2.38601, 3.09946, 4.22309, 
9.87019, 11.8278, 8.0656, 8.48857, 7.04588, 10.0083, 9.65277, 
8.26655, 4.26367, 4.21172, 4.45347, 5.1601, 10.0207, 10.7059, 
8.62925, 6.36322, 7.66119, 7.69737, 11.5594, 9.92093, 4.50141
)
```

Comment: how bout you provide us the data you're working with so we can help?

Comment: also you haven't defined n in your example...and your ``z`` object goes from capitalized to not capitalized.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, done

Comment: thats not a reproducible example. please dput() your data.

Comment: besides, thats only one vector of data, where's the second vector? you are computing a comparison test after all...

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, As I understand, the second vector is time.. I mean, the vector 1:n... Is it right?

Comment: Well... `n=length(timeseries)`... How to use it in the function then?

Comment: inside the function: ``cor.test(d,1:length(d) ,method="spearman")`` if ``d`` is your data

Answer (score 1):

```
#Figure out length of vector supplied by OP and create new vector
dn<-1:length(d) #if d refers to data supplied by OP

#Run the test
cor.test(d,dn,method="spearman") 

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  d and dn
S = 5447000, p-value = 0.4829
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
       rho 
0.03909714
```

Note the p-value of `0.4829` above. Now let's try an alternative method for finding spearman's rho using the `Hmisc` package:

```
rcorr(d,dn,type="spearman")
     x    y
x 1.00 0.04
y 0.04 1.00

n= 324 


P
  x      y     
x        0.4831
y 0.4831
```

Again note that they both have the same p-value of `0.4831`. So the test is correct. Now that we know the correlation coefficient for the Spearman's test is right let's move on to the trend test.

The OP is worried code for p-value from trend test is wrong. Instead of writing our own code why don't we make use of a user written package from CRAN and check our results against that:

```
library(trend)

partial.cor.trend.test(d,1:length(d), "spearman")
    Spearman's partial correlation trend test

data:  t AND  data  .  1:length(data)
t = 0, df = 322, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
r(tdata.1:length(data)) 
                      0
```

Note that the partial correlation test's p-value of `1` is identical to that of the OP's method. There is nothing wrong with either approaches. The p-value of 1 is likely an artifact of rounding up from some value near 1. You can look at various [posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15223/how-to-interpret-p-values-of-0-or-1) at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161545/what-does-a-p-value-of-exactly-1-0000-mean) to get a better sense of what's going on.

And as an aside, you can use Pearson's correlation for the trend test as well, like in the following:

```
partial.cor.trend.test(d,dn, "pearson")

    Pearson's partial correlation trend test

data:  t AND  data  .  dn
t = 0, df = 322, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
r(tdata.dn) 
          0
```

Again, note a p-value of `1` (or at least rounded to 1). I think the results confirm that there is no time trend in your data...Let's check this another way using a Partial Mann-Kendall Test, like in the following:

```
partial.mk.test(d,dn)

    Partial Mann-Kendall trend test

data:  t AND  data  .  dn
Z = -0.2954, p-value = 0.7677
alternative hypothesis: true trend exists in series
sample estimates:
           S         varS 
   -575.1424 3790753.7082
```

Note the p-value of `0.7677`. Also not significant. Simply put, you must reject your alternative hypothesis that a true trend exists in your time series.

Comment: Actually, I was not asking for the Correlation test... I am looking for a way to compute the Spearman's Rho Trend Test. Look that `Z` is my statistic